# Javascript. How do you make a loop that creates objects, then those objects being pushed into an array?

Tags: javascript, loops, class, object

So I started with importing 4 different arrays **with equal amounts of data**.

Then I made a class, thinking the class can help me make the objects, with that imported data.

So my thinking was if I loop through that class, it can make an object that contains the data of all 4 arrays by its index, and then push that object into an array.

I was hoping my ending results for **objectArray** would look like...

```
[ {nn: "Lion", dat1: 4, dat2: 9, dat3: 10}, {nn: "Zebra", dat1: 5, dat2: 10, dat3: 7}, {nn: "Monkey", dat1: 2, dat2: 6, dat3: 14} ...etc. ]
```

```js
// mock
const threeToType = {
   name: ["Lion", "Zebra", "Monkey"],
  data1: [     4,       5,        2],
  data2: [     9,      10,        6],
  data3: [    10,       7,       14],
};

const {name, data1, data2, data3} = threeToType; // require('./threeToType');

let objectArray = [];

class makeObj{
    constructor(nn, dat1, dat2, dat3){
        this._nn = nn;
        this._dat1 = dat1;
        this._dat2 = dat2;
        this._dat3 = dat3;
    }
}

for(let newObj, i = 0, tN = "", tD1 = 0, tD2 = 0, tD3 = 0; i<name.length; i++){

    tN = name[i];
    tD1 = data1[i];
    tD2 = data2[i];
    tD3 = data3[i];

    objectArray.push(newObj = new makeObj(tN, tD1, tD2, tD3));

}

console.log(objectArray);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what "it can make an object that contains the data of all 4 arrays by its index, and then push that object into an array." means exactly? I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ah nevermind I realized what you're trying to do. You want to turn rows into columns, if you're thinking of your 4 arrays as 4 rows in a table.

Comment: No, you don't need a `class` to help you with creating objects. A simple object literal would suffice. But regardless, your code should work. Does it not? What is the problem? What is the actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just simply:

```
const {name, data1, data2, data3} = require('./threeToType');
let objectArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
  let newItem = { nn: name[i], tD1: data1[i], tD2: data2[i], td3: data3[i] }
  objectArray.push(newItem)
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `name[i]`?  (you wrote `name[o]`...)

Answer (score 1):

Get your `nameArr`, `data1Arr`, `data2Arr`, and `data3Arr` from/how you wish - I've used some data for the snippet.

`map` iterates items in Array (`cv` here, unused) with their index (`idx` here).
We use that `idx` to retrieve "parallel" items from all arrays and make an object out of them.
We surroung the object with parentheses (`(` and `)`) because it is returned, and we don't want the browser to think it's code (`return` is a function, but we're allowed to omit the parentheses, here - we use them).

```js
nameArr=["Zebra", "Lion", "Elephant"];
data1Arr=[23, 12, 40];
data2Arr=["Africa", "America", "India"];
data3Arr=[true, false, true];

objArr=nameArr.map((cv, idx)=>({
  name:nameArr[idx],
  data1:data1Arr[idx],
  data2:data2Arr[idx],
  data3:data3Arr[idx]
}));

console.log(objArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please up-vote and select it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic solution, that assumes your input arrays are basically rows of a table (since they all have the same length), and you want to "flip" or invert them into columns. A two-dimensional array basically.

I'd keep the names of the input arrays out of this algorithm. There's no easy way to get the name of a variable (like "data1" in your snippet) as a string in JS.

You can call this with any number of arrays btw, as long as they all have the same length.

```
const invertRows = (...rows) => {
    const numRows = rows.length;
    const numColumns = rows[0].length;

    const inverted = new Array(numColumns);
    for (let col=0; col < numColumns; col++) {
        inverted[col] = new Array(numRows);
        for (let row=0; row < numRows; row++) {
            inverted[col][row] = rows[row][col];
        }
    }
    return inverted;
};

const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [3,4,5];

console.log(invertRows(arr1, arr2));

// Returns: [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 5 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently not really sure what you are asking, your current solution does work.

Here is a general purpose solution that transforms the data structure:

```
// from
const columns = {name: ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"], age: [42, 39]};
// into
const rows = [{name: "John Doe", age: 42}, {name: "Jane Doe", age: 39}];
// and the other way around.
```

```js
const threeToType = {
   name: ["Lion", "Zebra", "Monkey"],
  data1: [     4,       5,        2],
  data2: [     9,      10,        6],
  data3: [    10,       7,       14],
};

function columnsToRows(columns) {
  columns = Object.entries(columns);
  if (columns.length == 0) return [];
  
  const colLengths = columns.map(([,values]) => values.length);
  const maxColLength = Math.max(...colLengths);
  
  return Array.from({length: maxColLength}, (_, i) => {
    const row = Object.create(null);
    columns.forEach(([colName, values]) => row[colName] = values[i]);
    return row;
  });
}

function rowsToColumns(rows) {
  if (rows.length == 0) return {};
  const columns = Object.create(null);
  const colNames = new Set(rows.flatMap((row) => Object.keys(row)));
  
  colNames.forEach((colName) => columns[colName] = []);
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    colNames.forEach((colName) => columns[colName].push(row[colName]));
  });
  
  return columns;
}

console.log(columnsToRows(threeToType));
console.log(rowsToColumns(columnsToRows(threeToType)));
```